# sum of nodes of an linked list that contains int

Tags: c++, oop, linked-list

I'm trying to sum of elements of a linkedlist using class in c++.

for example : my linked list is 1->2->5 the sum should be 8.

here is how i created the linked list :

```
class Node{
    public:
        int num;
        Node* link;
};
class LinkedList{
    public:
        Node* head;
        LinkedList(){
            head == NULL;
        }
        void push(int num);
        void print_list();
};
```

and by this function I add nodes :

```
void LinkedList::push(int num){
        Node* new_node = new Node();
        new_node->num = num;
        new_node->link = head;
        head = new_node;
    }
```

now I need one more function to calculate the sum of int data of each nodes and i don't know how

I would appreciate any help

Comment: Hint: Start at `head`, and follow `node->link` until `node->link` is `nullptr`.  Keep a running sum as you go.

Comment: There are plethora of examples to find on the internet, how to iterate through a linked list??

Comment: *"One `head` to rule them all, one `head` to find them, One `head` to bring them all, and in the darkness sum them; In the Land of Mordor where the homework dies.*" to paraphrase. Should there really be just one global list pointed to by `head`?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply edit the traverse function to make it for the sum of the linked list as follows:

```
void sum()
{
    xop* temp = head;
    int sum;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        sum+=temp->data;
        temp = temp->nxt;
    }
    std::cout<<sum;
}
```